# how to get the photo link in tweets

Tags: php, twitter

i want to get the link of photo that attached in tweets
see the code :

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $user = "parsi_tweet";
}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $count = $_GET['count'];
} else {
    $count= "10";
}

$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {
    echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";
    exit();
}
foreach($string as $items){
    echo "TIME: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "TWEET: ". $items['text']."<br />";
    echo "BY: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "USERNAME: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
}
```

I can get the time of tweet by `echo "TIME: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";`
get the tweet text by `echo "TWEET: ". $items['text']."<br />";` and more informations that you can see in the code.
but how can i get the link of photo which attached in the tweet?! or how can i check that "is this tweet using photo?! or not?!
thanks for helping